# ¿Cómo ocultar la barra de estado solo cuando está en modo horizontal Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario rote su teléfono (Landscape) entre en FullScreen y oculte las barras de estado tanto inferior como superior, estoy usando esto...

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

y funciona perfectamente en modo vertical, ahora bien, cuando el usuario rote su teléfono (en modo horizontal) quiero que las barras de estado se oculten y entre en modo fullscreen.
¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas, define una variable tipo `Bundle` a nivel de clase

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
```

Sobre escribe los métodos de cambio de configuración para detectar la rotación, y llama el método para esconder la barra de estado cuando la orientación es `LANDSCAPE` (horizontal):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "change to ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE" );
        onSaveInstanceState(newBundle);

        hideSystemUI(); //*ocultar la barra de estado solo cuando está en modo horizontal.

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        onSaveInstanceState(newBundle);
        Log.d(TAG, "change to ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT" );
    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBundle("newBundle", newBundle);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getBundle("newBundle");
}
```

por último, dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` deseas [gestionar manualmente los cambios de configuración en tu aplicación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes?hl=es-419), debes declarar el atributo `android:configChanges` con el siguiente valor:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```